# Gmail-like labelling system

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am looking into a number of ways to implement a labelling system similar to the one in Gmail. Basically I have a Resource at the lowest level and I would like to provide a number of organisational groupings for that resource in the form of labels. If anyone has implemented something like that I would like to hear your views. My idea is to have within the Resource instance a `List<Label>`. I need to have an efficient mechanism in order to do very fast searches based on the labels or based on the resources.

Thanks
Dimitris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, I wouldn't do that. I'd think about maintaining two dictionaries, `Label -> HashSet<Resource>` and `Resource -> HashSet<Label>`. This will give you fast lookup in both directions. Obviously you should encapsulate this.

Also, whatever you do, you shouldn't embed it in your `Resource`. It's a resource, and it's maintaining its labels? No. Single responsibility and all that.

Comment: If I get this right you are talking about another class manager that will hold the two dictionaries and thus have the lookup functionality outside the Label and Resource instances.

Comment: What happens when you have like 10,000 or 100,000 Resources with the same label? Will the HashSet size not be too big? Is there a solution to that?